# Компилятор выдает ошибку (switch expression has illegal type)

Tags: функции, switch, микроконтроллеры

Добрый день! Почему switch выдает такую ошибку: (switch expression has illegal type)?

Программирую микроконтроллер от Silicon labs. В начале кода было объявление переменных: Led1 и Led2 - имеют значение либо 1 либо 0 (эти порты ведут к светодиодам -горит или не горит)

```
sbit   Led1        = P3^4;
sbit   Led2        = P3^5;
int flag = 0;
int flag2 = 0;

Led1      = 1;
Led2      = 0;
```

...

```
if(flag2 == 190) {
switch (Led1) 
{
case 0 : SFRPAGE = DAC0_PAGE;           
        Att[0]     =  Att[0] +1;
        DAC0_Code  =  GetDacValue( Att[0], ChS);
        DAC0       =  DAC0_Code; break;

case 1 :SFRPAGE = DAC1_PAGE;                
        Att[1]     =  Att[1] +1;
        DAC1_Code  =  GetDacValue( Att[1], ChS);
        DAC1       =  DAC1_Code; break;
}
flag2=0;
}
```

Comment: `sbit` не является целочисленным типом / енумератором?

Comment: вообще то является. а что?

Comment: и что это за тип?

Comment: 0 или 1. К чему вопрос?

Comment: 0 или 1 это не тип, а значение. А я спрашиваю про тип. Собственно значение тоже подозрительное, вы ведь присваиваете `Led1 = P3^4;` а потом вдруг 0 или 1...

Comment: Видимо этот тип нельзя использовать в switch, используйте if)

Comment: Это пин контроллера, который присоединен к диоду. И он может иметь значение либо 1 либо 0. И да, это если что не мой код...

Comment: "пин контроллера" это тоже не тип...

Comment: К чему этот вопрос здесь?

Comment: @Оскар к тому, что бы понять в чем именно проблема. Т.к. подобное сообщение компилятора появляется тогда, когда тип значения в свитче невозможно разрешить до enum или int.

Comment: Цитирую из учебника : "bit или sbit. Бит. Разрядность 1 бит, может принимать значение 1 или 0."

Comment: Ни в  С, ни в С++ нет типа "бит". Если это какой-то нестандартный тип, поддерживаемый этим компилятором, то для выяснения допустимых для него операций следует почитать документацию к компилятору.

Comment: @Оскар а вы уверены что правомерно использовать sbit в конструкциях switch? Ну, или попробуйте привести его к int "в лоб" switch((int)Led1) или switch((char)Led1)

Comment: @Sublihim Попробую ка я задать int, ибо char в моем случае- совсем не то..

Comment: должен быть тег C51 а не С

Comment: @VTT у меня uVIsion,там можно применять тип данных sbit для регистров специального назначения. В Silabs IDE тоже так можно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sbit  -это битовый SFR, заморочка C51, вы пишете под 8051 или аналогичную платформу. 
Это весьмя спецефичное расширение языка Си

```
sbit   Led1        = P3^4; // Led1 расположен по адресу со сдвигом 4 бита относительно sfr P3
```

Использовать их так в switch нельзя. Нужно считать значение, хотя бы во временную переменную.В случае sbit  достаточно использовать  if , у Вас нет третьего варианта, либо 0, либо 1!

Comment: ОК, спасибо за ответ. Придется использовать чехарду с if-ами, а не изящный switch...

Comment: @Оскар проверьте, работает ли ?: , (я не помню) выглядит короче, можно оформить отступами   и что может быть изящнее?  в любом случае компилятор превращает  switch   с двумя опциями в тот же код что и `if()  else if()`